# Combine multiple data into CSV

Tags: powershell

I didn't know how to title this question, but here is what I am trying to do:
The script below (MAIN SCRIPT) works fine! no problem.

I want to add the following:
Send a report to the $SENDER with everything that has been sent.  I just want a simple CSV with the following information: The **OwnerEmail.txt** and the **Subfolder Name and Creation Date**.

I kinda figured out how to collect the Cases (SubFolders) using (before ForEach look ends)

```
Export-Csv -Path 'C:\Test\WRA\CasesSent.csv' -Append
```

The problem is that this will only collect the Case Names (SubFolders), but it does not collect the parent folder or the OwnerEmail.txt

MAIN SCRIPT

```
# ================ Table HTML Setup ================
$Header = @"
<style>
TABLE {border-width: 1px; border-style: solid; border-color: black; border-collapse: collapse;}
TH {text-align: left}
TD {width: 150px; text-align: left; border-width: 1px; padding: 3px; border-style: solid; border-color: black;}
TR:nth-child(even) {background-color: #BDBDBD;}
</style>
"@

# ================ Initia Setup ================
$InitialFolder = "C:\Test\WRA"
$Sender = "miguel@company.com"
# ==============================================


$ParentFolders = Get-ChildItem -Path $InitialFolder -Directory | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName

foreach ($SubFolder in $ParentFolders) {
    $path = Join-Path $SubFolder -ChildPath 'OwnerEmail.txt'
    
    # If OwnerEmail.txt does not exist, skip 
    if (-not(Test-Path $path)){Continue}
    
    $Contact = Get-Content -Path ($SubFolder + "\OwnerEmail.txt")
    $emailTime = (Get-Date).ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")


# ================ Building HTML Report ================
    $WRAHTMLReport = Get-ChildItem -Path $SubFolder -Directory | 
    Select-Object Name, CreationTime |
    ConvertTo-Html -Head $Header -PreContent "
        <h2>Current Nuix Case(s)</h2> 
        <body>
            Report was sent on $emailTime
            <br></br>
            When you have a moment can you please confirm if any of these cases can be removed from Nuix:
        <body> 
        <br></br> " #|
    
    $WRAHTMLReport = $WRAHTMLReport -join ""
    Start-Sleep -s 2

# ================ Send Email ================
Send-MailMessage -SmtpServer mail.company.com -to $Contact -from $Sender -Subject "Nuix Cases" -Body $WRAHTMLReport -BodyAsHtml

}
```

Comment: What do you mean owneremail.txt? The full path to the file? The contents?

Comment: yea, the Owneremail.txt contains the Email of the person who owns the folder.  The full Path would also work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by adding the following command:

```
$ReportSubFolder = Get-ChildItem -Path $SubFolder -Directory | Select-Object Name
    $ReportContact = $Contact
    $ReportSubFolder = ($ReportSubFolder.Name -join "; ")

    $SenderReport = New-Object psobject
    $SenderReport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Case Owner" -Value $ReportContact
    $SenderReport | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name "Cases" -Value $ReportSubFolder

    $SenderReport | export-csv $SenderReportFile -Append
```